# Hidden input not submitted after updating value in on submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, forms, onsubmit

Using Laravel framework.

I don't get it. I have a hidden input with id = prime near the top.

```
<form name="paymentForm" action="/parking_302/upload_payment" method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" id="parking_lot_id" name="parking_lot_id" value="{{ $parking_lot_id }}">
    <input type="hidden" id="booking_id" name="booking_id" value="{{ $booking_id }}">
    <input type="hidden" id="Price" name="Price" value="{{ $Price }}">
    <input type="hidden" id="prime" name="prime">   {{-- To be obtained --}}

    <legend>電子發票 & TapPay 付款</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="CustomerEmail" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-4">電子信箱</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-8">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="CustomerEmail" name="CustomerEmail" value="{{ old('CustomerEmail') }}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="CustomerPhone" class="col-md-3 col-xs-4">手機號碼</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-8">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="CustomerPhone" name="CustomerPhone" value="{{ old('CustomerPhone') }}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-xs-offset-4 col-md-9 col-xs-8">
            <select class="form-control" id="giveTongBian" name="giveTongBian">
                <option value="no" @if(old('giveTongBian') === "no") selected @endif>不需統編</option>
                <option value="yes" @if(old('giveTongBian') === "yes") selected @endif>輸入統編</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="customerIdentGroup">
        <label for="CustomerIdentifier" class="col-md-3 col-xs-4">統一編號</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CustomerIdentifier" name="CustomerIdentifier" value="{{ old('CustomerIdentifier') }}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="customerNameGroup">
        <label for="CustomerName" class="col-md-3 col-xs-4">買受人</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CustomerName" name="CustomerName" value="{{ old('CustomerName') }}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="customerAddrGroup">
        <label for="CustomerAddr" class="col-md-3 col-xs-4">地址</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CustomerAddr" name="CustomerAddr" value="{{ old('CustomerAddr') }}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tappay-form col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
        <h4 style="color: darkkhaki;">信用卡</h4>
        <div class="form-group card-number-group">
            <label for="card-number" class="control-label"><span id="cardtype"></span>卡號</label>
            <div class="form-control card-number"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group expiration-date-group">
            <label for="expiration-date" class="control-label">卡片到期日</label>
            <div class="form-control expiration-date" id="tappay-expiration-date"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group cvc-group">
            <label for="cvc" class="control-label">卡片後三碼</label>
            <div class="form-control cvc"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Pay</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I then have a on submit event which does a few things. At the bottom is me updating the hidden input with id = prime.

```
$('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    //Code for first part of form begin
    var boolFlag = true;    //Default is submit
    var errorMsg = "";  //Initial message

    //Begin validation
    var numOfNonEmptyFields = 0;

    if(document.forms["paymentForm"]["CustomerEmail"].value != "") {
        numOfNonEmptyFields++;
    }

    if(document.forms["paymentForm"]["CustomerPhone"].value != "") {
        numOfNonEmptyFields++;
    }

    if(numOfNonEmptyFields == 0) {
        errorMsg += "請輸入至少一個電子信箱或手機號碼.\n";
        boolFlag = false;
    }
    //End validation

    //Final steps: overall error message + success or fail case
    if(boolFlag == false) {
        alert("錯誤:\n" + errorMsg);
        return false;
    }
    //Code for first part of form end

    // fix keyboard issue in iOS device
    forceBlurIos()

    const tappayStatus = TPDirect.card.getTappayFieldsStatus()
    console.log(tappayStatus)
    // Check TPDirect.card.getTappayFieldsStatus().canGetPrime before TPDirect.card.getPrime
    if (tappayStatus.canGetPrime === false) {
        bootbox.alert({
            title: "錯誤訊息",
            message: "取得不了Prime.",
            buttons: {
                ok: {
                    label: "OK",
                    className: "btn btn-primary"
                }
            }
        });
        return false
    }
    // Get prime
    TPDirect.card.getPrime(function (result) {
        if (result.status !== 0) {
            bootbox.alert({
                title: "錯誤訊息",
                message: result.msg,
                buttons: {
                    ok: {
                        label: "OK",
                        className: "btn btn-primary"
                    }
                }
            });
            return false
        }

        $("#prime").val(result.card.prime);
    })
})
```

I've tested the hidden input with alert($("#prime").val()) directly after and it seems updated, however after submission, my Controller receives the value as null while other hidden input values are correct. So I suspect it's something got to do with the on submit event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added id attribute to the form element:

```
<form id="paymentForm" name="paymentForm" action="/parking_302/upload_payment" method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
```

Removed type from the button and added id:

```
<button id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-default">Pay</button>
```

Introduced a new click listener:

```
$(document).on("click","#submit-btn", function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    validateAndSendForm();
});
```

Introduced a new function for the final form submit:

```
function submitForm(){
    //do other stuff here with the finalized form and data
    //.....

    $( "#paymentForm" ).submit();
}
```

And put all of your old things into a new function as well:

```
function validateForm(){
    //Code for first part of form begin
    var boolFlag = true;    //Default is submit
    var errorMsg = "";  //Initial message

    ...
    ...
    ...

    }
    // Get prime
    TPDirect.card.getPrime(function (result) {
        if (result.status !== 0) {
            bootbox.alert({
                title: "錯誤訊息",
                message: result.msg,
                buttons: {
                    ok: {
                        label: "OK",
                        className: "btn btn-primary"
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }

        $("#prime").val(result.card.prime);

        //use when you are ready to submit
        submitForm();
    })
}
```

So, basically you will have a "submitForm" function that you can use whenever you are ready to submit the form.

Comment: Thanks! I learnt from you and made lesser changes: 
1. added id to form.
2. removed type and added id to button.
3. changed my form on submit listener to submit-btn on click, keeping content inside the same.
4. added $("#paymentForm").submit() directly after my hidden input update.
But yeah, did you forget to mention the issue was the asynchronousity of the TPDirect.card.getPrime() function which we solved here by adding the submit function inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `TPDirect.card.getPrime` is something that gets data asynchronously so the `$('form').on('submit'` function won't wait for it to finish.

Comment: What can I do about this so I can have an updated hidden input before submission?

Comment: You could use the [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operator so the execution will wait until you get the result from that function. Keep in mind that if you want to work in older browsers you might need to use babel or a similar tool.